# Reading from Com port connected to em-18

Tags: java, serial-port

I wrote some code that is supposed to read data from my device. It compiles, but I'm not getting a SerialPortEvent. How can I get this to work?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.comm.*;

public class SimpleRead implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {
    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    static Enumeration portList;

    InputStream inputStream;
    SerialPort serialPort;
    Thread readThread;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {

            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
                 if (portId.getName().equals("COM5")) {
                    SimpleRead reader = new SimpleRead();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public SimpleRead() {
        try {
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);
        } catch (PortInUseException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        try {
            inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    try {
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);

    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        try {

            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        serialPort.setDTR(false);
                serialPort.setRTS(false);
        } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        readThread = new Thread(this);
        readThread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
       try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    }

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        switch(event.getEventType()) {
        case SerialPortEvent.BI:
        case SerialPortEvent.OE:
        case SerialPortEvent.FE:
        case SerialPortEvent.PE:
        case SerialPortEvent.CD:
        case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
        case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
        case SerialPortEvent.RI:
        case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];

            try {
                while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                }
                System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
            } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check your tags, using wrong tags will attract the wrong experts

Comment: Are you sure you use the methods in the correct order ? I think you try to read before you set up things like baud rate correctly. Did you check if com5 is the correct port and if other applications are able to retrieve data from your device ?

Comment: @TechWisdom Please slow down and ensure that you are actually fixing what needs to be fixed in the post, rather than applying trivial edits. On this post, you completely missed improperly formatted code. When editing, please evaluate the whole post to see what can be improved.